# Custom UITableView and custom UITableViewCells within ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Then, I have my ViewController displaying a TableView containing 2 custom cells:

[image]

So, I created 2 Cocoa Touch file classes: CellClassOne and CellClassTwo, I set the custom classes to appropriate cells in interface builder via the Identity Inspector, and after, I import header files to the View Controller implementation file:

[image: Headers]

And now I implement methods and protocols for UITableView (protocols declared in the ViewController header file), my code looks like this, but I know that it is not correct at all...

Am I missing some things ?

[image: cellClassTableView is the IBOutlet declared in ViewController.h by control drag in interface builder]

```
#pragma mark Cell Classes Table View data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 2;
}


- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        CellClassOne *cellClassOne = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellClassOne" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cellClassOne == nil) {

            cellClassOne = [[CellClassOne alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellClassOne"];
        }

        return cellClassOne;

    }

    else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        CellClassTwo *cellClassTwo = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellClassTwo" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cellClassTwo == nil) {

            cellClassTwo = [[CellClassTwo alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellClassTwo"];
        }

        return cellClassTwo;

    }

        return nil;
}


@end
```

Comment: What is your issue? Did you not get the correct output on the simulator?

Comment: That is the problem, I don't know what is the way I should take to display the TableView and the TableViewCells that I created in interface builder, should I have to create a cocoa touch class file for my custom Table View for example...
When I ran the simulator I was sure that it will crash...

Answer (score 0):

1.Select the cell1 in interface builder and assign the "CellClassOne" cellIdentifier there...Do the same for cell2 i.e. CellClassTwo.

2.Add UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate next to @interface ViewController

Comment: when you assign cellClassTableView.datasource and cellClassTableView.delegate to self, you assign the tableview to the code automatically.

Comment: Typecast the line (CellClassTwo/CellClassOne *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellClassTwo" forIndexPath:indexPath];     Post your crash logs after doing this

Comment: That's done, just before: [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier...] but the problem is not fixed, I can't run it on the simulator, it crashed  directly after the launchscreen displaying...

Comment: There is a property called as cellIdentifier in interface builder in storyboard.You have not set that identifier similar to the one in your code i.e. Identifier:@"CellClassOne"..This identifier is set in IB. Cell class name and identifier are seperate things

Comment: (that's the first part, characters are too long for character limit ^^)

2015-01-02 16:53:58.464 testTablView[4959:261838] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<CellClassOne 0x7fa5f2d2ae70> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key lblCellClass2.'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: Right click on the cell and its subviews in the storyboard..I think there is some wrong outlet connection in lblCellClass2

Comment: lblCellClass2 is declared in CellClassTwo.h (see first picture on my post)

Comment: The IBOutlet UILabel property is properly correct, that's not... and this is why I don't understand the problem...

Comment: I checked that, and it's not, the label is only connected to the CellClassTwo.h